# Java - get JTextArea's size after changing text

Tags: java, swing, resize, jtextarea

Is there any way in Java how to get preferred size of JTextArea after changing its text besides multiplying rows and columns?

Here's an example:

```
JTextArea a = new JTextArea("sooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo long line"+
        "\nfoo\nboo\nbar\nmoo\nso\nlong\ntext");
Dimension p1 = a.getPreferredSize();
Dimension s1 = a.getSize();

a.append("some\nmore\ntext");
//a.recomputeSize(); I need something like this
Dimension p2 = a.getPreferredSize();
Dimension s2 = a.getSize();

System.out.println(p1); //[width=302,height=128]
System.out.println(s1); //[width=0,height=0]
System.out.println(p2); //[width=302,height=128]
System.out.println(s2); //[width=0,height=0]
```

Comment: When I tested this (in Java 1.7.0_13) it worked: the JTextArea's preferred size was updated immediately.  Is it possible your code is not running in the AWT event dispatch thread?

Comment: well, this is in main() method, i didnt even add this area anywhere in order to simplify the problem, but ill try it

Comment: In the end, the problem was that originaly, i was setting PreferredSize so the pack() had something to work with, so all i had to do was to call setPreferredSize(null) after the pack() method. Thanks anyway :)

Comment: @kajacx Do you want to add what you did as an answer so others can see how to solve?

Comment: @DonyorM unfortunatelly i had this problem 3 years ago so i don't remember how i solved this. From my comment i remember it had to do something with the `pack()` method maybe?